# Shift + arrow for multiple files or folders selection

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I was wondering why I cannot select anymore multiple files or folders in Files using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> in Grid view. 
That works fine in List view using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Comment: Did it use to work correctly at the beginning? If so, since when did it stop working? What kind of changes did you make to your system around that time?

Comment: It was working before upgrading to 18.04 LTS